# Azure Data Factory Sink Destination Filter

Tags: sql, azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

How can I add filter in the update sink operation in the destination table using Azure Data Factory.

Basically I am trying to implement the below query and I need the filter end_date = '9999-12-31 in the destination sink.

```
update testdb.test_scd2
set end_date = SourceStream.end_date
where cust_id = SourceStream.cust_id
and end_date = '9999-12-31
```

'
ADF Script - Updated based on comment from Mark. But it is updating all data in destination table. Only need to update one row with end_date - '9999-12-31'

```
source(output(
        cust_id as string,
        end_date_new as date
    ),
    allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    ignoreNoFilesFound: false,
    wildcardPaths:['walgreen/source/test_upd.dat']) ~> FFWCustomerUpd
source(output(
        cust_id as string,
        eff_date as date,
        end_date as date,
        first_name as string,
        last_name as string,
        status as string
    ),
    allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    ignoreNoFilesFound: false,
    isolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED',
    format: 'table') ~> source1
Exists1 alterRow(updateIf(1==1)) ~> AlterTeradataConnectorupd
source1 filter(end_date==toDate('9999-12-31')) ~> Filter1
FFWCustomerUpd, Filter1 exists(FFWCustomerUpd@cust_id == source1@cust_id,
    negate:false,
    broadcast: 'auto')~> Exists1
AlterTeradataConnectorupd sink(input(
        cust_id as string,
        eff_date as date,
        end_date as date,
        first_name as string,
        last_name as string,
        status as string
    ),
    allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    deletable:false,
    insertable:false,
    updateable:true,
    upsertable:false,
    keys:['cust_id'],
    format: 'table',
    mapColumn(
        cust_id,
        end_date = end_date_new
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> TeradataConnectorupd
```

[image: Dataflow]

[image: Destination table after update]

Answer (score 1):

Set the policy in your Alter Row for "Update If": end_date == 9999-12-31

In the sink, set your key column to cust_id

Comment: "Update If" is the filtering for the incoming row or the table we are updating?

Comment: Incoming row. If you're just trying to update rows in your target database, then set the source to be the same dataset as your target.

Comment: In the dataflow - FFWCustomerUpd is the csv file with record cust_id = 1001 and end_date = 2020-10-01. I would like to update the destination table to the end_daate in csv file file if the destination table end_date = '9999-12-31'. How do i specify the end_date of destination sink to only pick 9999-12-31?

Comment: In the data flow, your stream is only looking at filtering incoming data. If you need to check for a value from the target data, you should add another source to your data flow that queries your target table and looks for dates that equal '9999-12-31'. Then, you can Join with your new data stream and set the new end date. I'll paste a screenshot example in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the pseudo-code outline for what the logical flow would look like:

1. New incoming source + target table as a source
2. In bottom stream, filter just the dates you need to replace
3. Filter for just the IDs that have that date in top stream
4. Set Alter Row to true() for Update so all rows will update. At this point, we are confident they are all 9999-12-31
5. Write to sink with "Allow Updates" only set

[image]

Comment: Kromer - I am trying to do Type 2 SCD. There could be multiple columns in the target with same cust_id with different end_date. The above flow will update all records with cust_id =  1001  right? We are not filtering anything in the destination sink and the key column is only cust_id. I tried to join the end_date, but I am getting the below error. - Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'TeradataConnectorupd': No updateable columns match with the schema of sink table."

Comment: My sample above only updates rows that had '9999-12-31' as the date. If you set cust_id as the primary key in the sink, this will update any cust_id to a new date if the previous value was 9999-12-31.

Comment: I followed your code, but it is updating all the rows for that cust_id. I posted in the new code in the question. Is there anything I am missing there?

Comment: Can you click Data Preview in your Sink transformation and look for the rows that are coming out of the Sink. Check there to see if the correct rows are being updated.

Comment: Also, you can validate that only the rows with 9999-12-31 are being filtered by checking the data preview on the alter row transformation.